# cocos2d game becomes slow after checking notification center in IOS7

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ios7

After upgraded to ios7, I found the Cocos2d application run slowly (or frame skipped) after checking the notification center.
Reproduce the problem:

1. Launch a cocos2d game, better with some fast moving sprites
2. Swipe down from the top of the screen to drop down the notifaction center, then swipe it up.
3. Now the game becomes like frame skipped. (slow). But after a while, or after some operation within the game, the frame speed recovers.

I tested on iphone5.

Anyone see the same problem? Any idea how it happens?

EDIT:
Since this problem only happens in rare case, I d like to close it.

Comment: Reboot the device. If this persists it may very well be normal system behavior. Keep in mind that the cocos2d fps counter lags behind, if you want to see it more accurately then change the update rate in ccConfig.h

Comment: This makes me hard to continue my development of a cocos2d game. I need to find the reason how it happens on ios7, and a smooth framerate is too important for the interactivity of a game.

Comment: Well you have to ask yourself how often are users going to check the notification center while playing the game? Is it going to be significant? Why not just pause the game when the notification center comes up (good practice anyway) and then have the user press a button to continue. That way there ought to be enough time for fps to recover. Finally maybe you're (or cocos2d is) doing something in the delegate methods: resign active and will enter foreground that causes delay, such as uncaching/reloading textures.